# Plural de substantivos compostos: e.g. por que “cavalos-vapor” mas “decretos-leis”?

Tags: número-gramatical, morfologia, nomes-compostos

As vezes fico confuso com a flexão de substantivos compostos. A seguir alguns exemplos:

> Exemplo (1):
> Cavalo-vapor / para-lama
> Cavalos-vapor / para-lamas
>
> Exemplo (2):
> Decreto-lei / matéria-prima
> Decretos-leis / matérias-primas
>
> Exemplo (3):
> Salvo-conduto / vice-diretor
> Salvos-condutos / vice-diretores
>
> Exemplo (4):
> Surdo-mudo / bem-falante
> Surdos-mudos / bem-falantes

Os exemplos são de Fernando Moura, *Gramática aplicada ao texto*, Vestacon: Brasilia-DF, 2005, e usados em comentários sobre uma questão de concurso da Universidade de Brasília: UnB.

Qual é a regra que foi utilizada para flexionar ou não os elementos desses substantivos?

Comment: Não seria melhor indicar a fonte dos exemplos?

Comment: Sim, editei a pergunta.

Comment: Salvo-conduto parece violar a "regra". Quando há um adjetivo, só o substantivo fica no plural. Bem-falente, por ex., é um adjetivo e um substantivo. Então no plural, bem-falantes. Igual que para-lamas. Ë um verbo (parar) que funciona como adjetivo. Em francês, esse salvo-conduto, não fica salvos-condutos (sauf-conduites). Nem vejo a razão do s em português. Salvo é adjetivo. Seguindo a regra, deveria ser: salvo-condutos. Então não sei responder bem....Parece que os dois se admitem....

Comment: @Lambie   "bem-falante" me parece ser um advérbio e um adjetivo. "Ele é um indivíduo bem-falante"  "Ele é muito falante".

Comment: @Centaurus falante: utilizador de uma língua ou locutor. O bem é adjetivo. Um cavalo falante, o que fala, o falante é adjetivo....

Comment: @Lambie  Na frase "ele é um indivíduo bem-falante",   "bem falante" é uma locução adjetiva composta por um advérbio (bem) e um adjetivo (falante).  **"bem-falante" qualifica o substantivo "indivíduo"**.  Um cavalo falante, é certamente um cavalo que fala.e, nesse caso, "falante" também é um adjetivo.   Já em "o falante da língua portuguesa tem certa dificuldade em...",  "falante" é um substantivo.  "

Comment: Todos os exemplos dados acima são :  "a flexão de substantivos compostos." Todos são substantivos. Falante pode ser USADO como adjetivo como no seu exemplo, e bem virá advérbio, más no caso de substantivo bem funciona COMO adjetivo. Esse senhor é um bem falante.

Comment: @Lambie   Sim, precedido de artigo ("um bem-falante")  "bem-falante" passa a ser uma locução substantiva. Contudo, embora gramaticalmente correta, essa frase não é idiomática como "Esse senhor é bem falante".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

«Não é fácil a formação do plural dos substantivos compostos» — é como Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra abrem a exposição do assunto na *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* (Lisboa, 2014, p. 248-50). E [este artigo no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/plural-dos-nomes-compostos/3494) diz que o assunto é «por vezes, complicado e um tanto controverso». Mas lá apresentam algumas regularidades. O que se segue baseia-se sobretudo no Cunha e Cintra. Confirmei a correção de todos os exemplos no [Vocabulário Ortográfico Comum](http://voc.cplp.org/index.php?action=von&csl=br).

**Verbo + substantivo**. O verbo não se altera, e só o segundo elemento é que passa para o plural:

> guarda-chuva, guarda-chuvas
>   pica-pau, pica-paus
>   para-sol, para-sóis

Está também neste caso o *para-lama, para-lamas*. Com uma observação: podemos também usar *para-lamas* como substantivo singular: *um para-lamas*. Isto é comum com este tipo de substantivos. Mais exemplos de substantivos de dois números: *abre-latas, saca-rolhas, quebra-nozes, para-raios*.

**Advérbio, prefixo ou elemento que funcione como prefixo + substantivo ou adjetivo**. Advérbios e prefixos são invariáveis, portanto só o segundo elemento é que passa para o plural. Caiem neste caso os teus exemplos *vice-diretor* e *bem-falante*. Outros exemplos:

> abaixo-assinado, abaixo-assinados
>   sempre-viva, sempre-vivas
>   pré-história, pré-histórias
>   arqui-inimigo, arqui-inimigos

**Adjetivo e Substantivo**. Normalmente os dois elementos passam ao plural. É o caso do teu exemplo *matéria-prima* e *salvo-conduto*. Outros exemplos:

> Amor-perfeito, amores-perfeitos
>   Gentil-homem, gentis-homens
>   Alto-comissário, altos-comissários

**Dois substantivos**. Este é o caso mais complicado. O mais comum é ambos os elementos passarem ao plural (indico apenas os plurais): *surdos-mudos, tenentes-coronéis, tios-avôs*
Mas há uma exceção: só o primeiro elemento passa ao plural quando o segundo substantivo «funciona como determinante específico» (Cunha e Cintra, p. 249). Por exemplo, *livro-caixa, livros-caixa*. O *livro-caixa* é um livro onde se registam as entradas e saídas de dinheiro em caixa. Portanto *caixa* determina o tipo do livro; não se pode dizer o inverso, que *livro* determina o tipo de caixa; nem se pode dizer que *livro-caixa* seja livro e caixa ao mesmo tempo, ou uma coisa intermédia entre livro e caixa. Cunha e Cintra dão como exemplos (indico apenas o plural) *navios-escola, salários-família, bananas-prata, mangas-espada*; no Ciberdúvidas temos ainda *cafés-concerto* e *livros-razão*. E está neste caso o teu *cavalos-vapor*.

O problema é que ou esta regra não é sempre seguida ou nem sempre é claro se o segundo substantivo determina o tipo do primeiro. E alguns exemplos dados pelo Cunha e Cintra e artigo do Ciberdúvidas como pertencendo a esta categoria aparecem no [Vocabulário Ortográfico Comum (navio-escola)](http://voc.cplp.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=64263) e em vários dicionários com dois plurais possíveis:

> Navio escola: *navios-escola* ou *navios-escolas*
>   Café-concerto: *cafés-concerto* ou *cafés-concertos*

Também *decreto-lei*, contrariamente à opinião do Fernando Moura, admite os plurais *decretos-lei* e *decretos-leis*. Alguns casos onde há consenso que apensas o primeiro exemplo passa ao plural: *livros-caixa, livros-razão, cavalos-vapor, anos-luz, banana-prata*.