# Qual é o plural de "vale-compra"?

Tags: número-gramatical, nomes-compostos

***Vale-compra*** é uma espécie de código ou cupom usado para fornecer descontos em lojas, tanto físicas quanto virtuais. Em lojas *online* é frequente o uso desta expressão, mas fiquei com dúvida hoje ao tentar escrever o plural de *vale-compra*. Preciso escrever algo assim:

> Você concorrerá a 30 ***vale(s)-compra(s)*** ao concluir a transação.

Ficou a dúvida: o certo é ***vales-compra***, ***vale-compras*** ou ***vales-compras***? Todas são aceitas?

Não encontrei fontes muito boas sobre o assunto, mas acredito que elas existam.

No [Manual de Redação d’*O Estado de S. Paulo*](http://area50.estadao.com.br/manualredacao/esclareca/v.shtm) diz que o correto é *vales-compra*.

No [blog *Língua Portuguesa no Dia a Dia*](http://linguaportuguesanodiaadia.blogspot.com.br/2007/12/vales-transporte-ou-vales-transportes.html) a resposta é um pouco diferente.

Comment: Já temos [esta pergunta genérica sobre plural de substantivos compostos](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3550/plural-de-substantivos-compostos-e-g-por-que-cavalos-vapor-mas-decretos-lei), mas este parece ser um dos casos complicados.

Comment: O que eu esperaria seria "vales-compra", e acho que a resposta que o @Jacinto hiper-ligou concorda. Mas não sei justificar isto, exceto "porque é assim a regra, vê a resposta do Jacinto àqueloutra pergunta relacionada".

Comment: O link para o manual de redação do Estado de SP diz que o acesso é restrito.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As duas versões—*vales-compra* e *vales-compras*—são aceites. O [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=vale-compra) é único dicionário em que encontrei *vale-compra*, e admite estes dois plurais. Mas substantivos compostos análogos aparecem também com os dois plurais em vários dicionários, incluindo o Houaiss, e na [Academia Brasileira de Letras](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario):

> *Vale-refeição*. Plural: *vales-refeição* ou *vales-refeições*;
>
> *Vale-transporte*. Plural: *vales-transporte* ou *vales-transportes*.

No entanto a *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (Lisboa, 2014), apresenta um argumento, a que eu sou sensível, a favor de *vales-compra*. É o seguinte. Um vale-compra é um vale; não é uma compra. Logo o substantivo *compra*, na linguagem da *Nova Gramática* (p. 249), “funciona como um determinante específico”, ou seja determina o tipo de vale. Nestes casos, diz a *Nova Gramática*, apenas o primeiro elemento toma a forma de plural. Isto, em oposição a nomes como *tios-avôs* ou *tenentes-coronéis*, em que ambos os substantivos estão em pé de igualdade, tomando ambos a forma de plural.

Agora, como vimos, esta regra não é seguida por autoridades com o peso do dicionário Houaiss ou a [Academia Brasileira de Letras](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario), que indicam os dois plurais para substantivos compostos em que na *Nova Gramática* apenas o primeiro recebe a forma de plural [ver esta pergunta sobre o assunto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3550/plural-de-substantivos-compostos-e-g-por-que-cavalos-vapor-mas-decretos-lei). Outros exemplos com a mesma lógica—o segundo substantivo apenas determina o tipo do primeiro—que quer no Houaiss quer na Academia admitem os dois tipos de plural:

> *Salário-família*. Plural: *salários-família* ou *salários-famílias*:
>
> *Mestre-escola*. Plural: *mestres-escola* ou *mestres-escolas*.
>
> *Peixe-espada*. Plural: *peixes-espada* ou *peixes-espadas*.

O [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/vale-compra) opta por uma terceira forma: substantivo de dois números *o/os vale-compras!* Não vejo como justificar esta opção. Por um lado não sei se alguém diz *o vale-compras*; segundo, *os vale-compras* implicaria tomar *vale* como verbo—como *o/os saca-rolhas, o/os limpa-vidros*—mas não vejo por que fazer isso quando o substantivo [*vale* (Aulete²)](http://www.aulete.com.br/vale) está mais que consagrado.

A aceitabilidade dos dois plurais—*vales-compra* e *vales-compras*—está na linha do que eu já tinha constatado na minha resposta a esta [pergunta sobre o plural de nomes compostos](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3550/plural-de-substantivos-compostos-e-g-por-que-cavalos-vapor-mas-decretos-lei). Finalmente nota que o [Manual de Redação d’*O Estado de S. Paulo*](http://area50.estadao.com.br/manualredacao/esclareca/v.shtm) não está em oposição com o [blog](http://linguaportuguesanodiaadia.blogspot.pt/2007/12/vales-transporte-ou-vales-transportes.html), o Houaiss ou a Academia Brasileira de Letras. Um manual de redação pode simplesmente anunciar a sua preferência entre as várias alternativas gramaticais. E é isso que, perante os factos, eu faço: prefiro *os vales-compra* pelas razões avançadas lá em cima.

Comment: Esse uso da palavra "aceite", típico de pt-PT,  me faz lembrar de azeites espanhóis.

Comment: @Centaurus É, *aceite* é como se diz por cá.

Comment: @eight Então afinal, já que concordas com aceitabilidade de *vales-compra* e *vales-compras*, vais usar qual? E obrigado pelo edit: isto é o que dá andar a escrever e a reescrever.

Comment: @Jacinto obrigado. Eu acho todos "feios", mas também prefiro vales-compra.

Comment: Também acho estranha a forma do verbo aceitar, "aceites", quase como a tradução espanhola para azeite. Prefiro dizer e escrever "aceitos" ou "aceitas".

Comment: Eu usaria vales-compras. Mas estou na dúvida também de tornar o último elemento em singular, como diz abaixo o Centaurus.

Comment: @tuca, é com certeza uma questão de hábito: *aceite* soa-me normalíssimo, porque foi o que sempre ouvi.

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo as regras da boa gramática no que toca ao plural dos substantivos compostos, eu diria "os vales-compra".  Da mesma forma que digo:

- os vales-refeição
- os papéis-moeda
- os salários-família
- os pombos-correio

Para maiores detalhes ver [Plural de substantivos compostos: e.g. por que “cavalos-vapor” mas “decretos-leis”?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3550/plural-de-substantivos-compostos-e-g-por-que-cavalos-vapor-mas-decretos-lei)  onde uma pergunta mais abrangente foi respondida por Jacinto.

Comment: Eu também prefiro *vales-refeição* e *salários-família*, mas todos os dicionários que consultei e a Academia Brasileira de Letras aceitam os dois plurais nos teus quatro exemplos.

Answer (score 0):

O plural correto de *vale-compra* é *vales-compra*, onde somente o primeiro termo varia.

A regra é a seguinte: o plural de nomes compostos por justaposição, em que o segundo elemento exerce uma função ou finalidade do primeiro, somente o primeiro termo ou elemento sofre variação na pluralização do referido substantivo composto.

A mesma regra é seguida pelos seguintes substantivos compostos: *vale-brinde*, *vale-refeição*, *navio-escola*, onde todos eles apresentam o segundo termo ou elemento exercendo uma função ou objetivo do primeiro. Em todos estes casos, os plurais são flexionados com a variação apenas do primeiro termo, permanecendo invariável o segundo termo. Então: *vales-brinde*, *vales-refeição*, *navios-escola*.

Comment: Seria bom dizer de quem é essa regra, até porque o [dicionário Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/vale-compra/) admite o plural *vales-compras*, e a [Academia Brasileira de Letras](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario) admite plurais como *vales-refeições* e *vales-transportes*.