# Plural de "factura/recibo"

Tags: número-gramatical

Qual o plural de "factura/recibo" nas finanças de Portugal?

1. facturas / recibos
2. factura / recibos
3. facturas / recibo

Contexto:
`Listagem das suas "factura/recibo"`

Comment: Em pt-BR, não vejo porque não possa ser faturas/recibos.

Comment: Não penso que  haja um diferença entre pt-BR e pt-PT neste caso para o plural. A diferença é entre factura (pt-PT) e fatura (pt-BR).

Comment: Imagino que te refiras ao documento único que serve simultaneamente de fatura e recibo. Nesse caso, embora se encontre por aí "fatura/recibo", a grafia correta é com hífen, *fatura-recibo* (vê [Dicionário da Porto Editora](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/fatura#fatura-recibo)), como é normal nos substantivos compostos, e o plural é *faturas-recibos*. Vê [esta pergunta sobre o plural dos substantivos compostos](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3550/plural-de-substantivos-compostos-e-g-por-que-cavalos-vapor-mas-decretos-lei).

Comment: @Jacinto de facto assim parece melhor "faturas-recibos". Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, vamos iniciar com a definição da barra oblíqua:

> A barra oblíqua é um sinal gráfico usado:
>
> Para indicar disjunção e exclusão, podendo ser substituída pela
>   conjunção ou.
>
> Poderemos optar por: carne/peixe/dieta. Poderemos optar por: carne,
>   peixe ou dieta. Para indicar inclusão, quando utilizada na separação
>   das conjunções e/ou.
>
> Os alunos poderão apresentar trabalhos orais e/ou escritos. As
>   avaliações serão feitas com base nas notas dos testes e/ou trabalhos.
>   Para indicar itens que possuem algum tipo de relação entre si.
>
> A palavra será classificada quanto ao número (plural/singular). A
>   professora de português explicou a relação hipertexto/hipotexto. O
>   carro atingiu os 220 km/h. Para separar os versos de poesias, quando
>   escritos seguidamente na mesma linha. São utilizadas duas barras para
>   indicar a separação das estrofes.
>
> "[…] De tanto olhar para longe,/não vejo o que passa perto,/meu peito
>   é puro deserto./Subo monte, desço monte.//Eu ando sozinha/ao longo da
>   noite./Mas a estrela é minha." Cecília Meireles "Amor é um fogo que
>   arde sem se ver/É ferida que dói, e não se sente/É um contentamento
>   descontente/É dor que desatina sem doer." Luís de Camões  Na escrita
>   abreviada, para indicar que a palavra não foi escrita na sua
>   totalidade.
>
> a/c = aos cuidados de; s/ = sem; c/ = com. Para separar o numerador do
>   denominador nos números fracionários, substituindo a barra da fração.
>
> 1/3 = um terço; 1/2 = um meio; 1/5 = um quinto. Para separar números,
>   como o dia, mês e ano nas datas; a parte final de números de telefone
>   diferentes; o número do prédio e apartamento nos endereços; os dois
>   anos consecutivos em que ocorre algum evento.
>
> Nas datas: 31/03/1983 Nos números de telefone: 225 03 50/51/52 Nos
>   endereços: Rua do Limoeiro, 165/232 Na indicação de dois anos
>   consecutivos: O evento de 2012/2013 foi um sucesso. Para indicar
>   fonemas, ou seja, os sons da língua.
>
> /s/; /x/; /o/. Nota: Embora não existam regras muito definidas sobre a
>   existência de espaços antes e depois da barra oblíqua, privilegia-se o
>   seu uso sem espaços: plural/singular, masculino/feminino,
>   sinônimo/antônimo.

Fonte: [Norma Culta](https://www.normaculta.com.br/barra-obliqua/)

Com essa informação e também com o contexto dado, quando colocar no plural, vai continuar querendo facturar ou recibos:

**Então ficaria:**

Listagem de suas facturas/recibos

**ou ainda trocando a Barra obliqua por ou:**

Listagem de suas facturas ou recibos.

Comment: Queres dizer "vai continuar querendo faturas ou recibos"? Tens "faturar". Tudo isto está bem, mas eu creio que "fatura/recibo" (que significaria, como dizes, 'fatura ou recibo') é apenas uma grafia "criativa" de *fatura-recibo*, que é um documento único que serve de fatura e recibo ao mesmo tempo. Alertei o perguntador para esclarecer.

Comment: Concordo. Se for factura-recibo, a regra já muda pelo o que pesquisei.

Comment: Sim, mas o resultado é análogo: o plural é *faturas-recibos*. O "normal" quando temos dois substantivos ligados por hífen é pluralizar os dois; há alguns casos em que se pode ou deve mesmo pluralizar apenas o primeiro--*anos-luz, mestres-escola*, etc.-- mas *fatura-recibo* não está nesse caso. Vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3550/plural-de-substantivos-compostos-e-g-por-que-cavalos-vapor-mas-decretos-lei) e [esta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4065/qual-%C3%A9-o-plural-de-vale-compra?noredirect=1&lq=1).