# "Códigos ramal" ou "códigos ramais" qual a forma correta?

Tags: português-europeu, colocação-pronominal, caso-gramatical

"Códigos ramal" ou "códigos ramais" qual a forma correta ?

Comment: CIMend, porque é que não nos explicas o que é o código ramal? A pergunta ficaria bem mais clara (pelo menos para leigos) Entretanto vê se [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3550/plural-de-substantivos-compostos-e-g-por-que-cavalos-vapor-mas-decretos-lei) e mais [esta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4065/qual-%c3%a9-o-plural-de-vale-compra) te ajudam.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qual é o plural de "vale-compra"?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4065/qual-%c3%a9-o-plural-de-vale-compra)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que seja **códigos ramais** visto que nos casos de substantivo + substantivo, ambos vão para o plural quando se deduz que há autonomia de significado em cada um.

Segundo o *site* Guia do Estudante:

https://guiadoestudante.abril.com.br/blog/duvidas-portugues/aprenda-de-vez-o-plural-de-nomes-compostos/

> Norma geral: nos substantivos compostos vão para o plural apenas as palavras que forem substantivo ou adjetivo, inclusive ambos juntos. Os demais, de forma geral, não variam.
>
> Exemplos:
>
> - O guarda-chuva, os guarda-chuvas (verbo + substantivo).
> - O abaixo-assinado, os abaixo-assinados (advérbio + adjetivo).
> - O guarda-noturno, os guardas-noturnos (guarda aqui é substantivo + adjetivo).
> - A má-formação, as más-formações. (adjetivo + substantivo).
>
> Como desdobramento dessa regra geral, temos:
>
> Se a palavra for composta por verbo + substantivo, só o substantivo vai para o plural.  – O/A caça-fantasma, os/as caça-fantasmas.
>
> - O beija-flor, os beija-flores.
> - Um cachorro vira-lata, uns cães vira-latas.
>
> E se o composto verbo + substantivo já for plural, faz-se a flexão apenas com o artigo que o antecede.
>
> Exemplos:
>
> - o/a caça-dotes, os/as caça-dotes.
> - o saca-rolhas, os saca-rolhas.
>
> Nos casos de substantivo + substantivo, ambos vão para o plural quando
>   se deduz que há autonomia de significado em cada um. Para descobrir se
>   esse é o caso, é só verificar se, na expressão, caberia a conjunção
>   “e” ligando-os.  Exemplos:
>
> - A couve-flor, as couves-flores (essa verdura é couve, e é flor).
> - O cirurgião-dentista, os cirurgiões-dentistas (eles são cirurgiões e também são dentistas). E também Cirurgiã-dentista, cirurgiãs-dentistas.
> - Meia-calça, meias-calças (são ambas as coisas).
> - Redator-chefe, redatores-chefes.
>
> Nos casos de substantivo + substantivo em que há relação de subordinação – ou seja, o primeiro elemento é determinante do segundo –, só vai para o plural a primeira palavra.
>
> - Bomba-relógio, bombas-relógio.
> - Palavra-chave, palavras-chave.
>
> Os casos de substantivo + substantivo ligados por preposição se enquadram na mesma definição anterior, em que o primeiro elemento é determinante do segundo. Portanto, nesses casos, apenas o primeiro elemento flexiona para o plural.
>
> - Pé de moleque, pés de moleque.
> - Água-de-colônia, águas-de-colônia.
>
> Substantivos compostos com sufixos: apenas o substantivo vai para o plural Acreditamos que você não erraria esses, mas não custa anotar.
>
> - Cursinho semi-intensivo, cursinhos semi-intensivos.
> - Recém-nascido, recém-nascidos.
> - Recém-formado, recém-formados.
> - A seu bel-prazer, a seus bel-prazeres.
>
> Há mais casos? Sim, mas são as raríssimas exceções. Você se sairá bem usando o bom-senso.

Comment: Kaldwin, poderia copiar o texto da tua referencia e colocar aqui? Caso o link quebre, ainda temos o conteudo

Comment: A fonte cita todas as outras formas de plural de nomes compostos, mas decidi colocar apenas o que ele fala sobre o caso do OP. Achas que eu deveria postar todas as outras formas de plural de nomes compostos?

Comment: Sim, mas isso pode quebrar, trocar o link e tudo mais e perdemos a explicação. Se puder copiar e citar aqui, seria ótimo!