# Qual a diferença entre "fins de semana" e "fins de semanas"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, gramática

Qual é a diferença entre **fins de semanas** e **fins de semana**?

> Ele lava o carro nos fins de semana.
>
> Ele lava o carro nos fins de semanas.

A primeira está dizendo que ele faz isso um dia no final da semana e a segunda diz que ele faz isso nos finais de todas as semanas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não, **o plural de fim-de-semana é fins-de-semana**, conforme cita o [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/fim%20de%20semana). Dizer fins-de-semanas é tão errado quanto pés-de-moleques ou estrelas-dos-mares.

> - [*Fins de semana*](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/1088) é o plural da locução fim de semana  e *finais de semana* é a forma plural da locução final de semana, pelo que ambos estão corretos.
> - substantivo + substantivo ligados por preposição, apenas o primeiro elemento flexiona para o plural. 
>     – Pé de moleque, pés de moleque.
>     – Água-de-colônia, águas-de-colônia.   [GdoE](https://guiadoestudante.abril.com.br/blog/duvidas-portugues/aprenda-de-vez-o-plural-de-nomes-compostos/)

Temos **excelentes respostas** sobre o plural de palavras compostas em:

- [Plural de substantivos compostos: e.g. por que “cavalos-vapor” mas “decretos-leis”?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3550/plural-de-substantivos-compostos-e-g-por-que-cavalos-vapor-mas-decretos-lei/3562#3562)
- [“Códigos ramal” ou “códigos ramais” qual a forma correta?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/6607/c%c3%b3digos-ramal-ou-c%c3%b3digos-ramais-qual-a-forma-correta/6608#6608)