# Plural: Focas-leopardo, Focas-leopardos ou focas leopardos?

Tags: português-brasileiro, ortografia, número-gramatical, hífen, nomes-compostos

Devo usar o **hífen** para escrever *"focas-leopardo*" ou escreve-se *"focas leopardos"*? Como se escreve o plural do substantivo composto?

Comment: Relacionado: [Plural de substantivos compostos: e.g. por que “cavalos-vapor” mas “decretos-leis”?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3550/plural-de-substantivos-compostos-e-g-por-que-cavalos-vapor-mas-decretos-lei)

Comment: Elisson, se a repsosta esclareceu a sua pergunta não se esqueça de [marcar em como aceita a resposta clicando a marca verde do lado esquerdo da resposta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quer o singular quer o plural se escrevem com hífen. O [Acordo Ortográfico de 1990](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1990) suprimiu alguns hífens usados anteriormente, mas a Base III, ponto 3, determina que se emprega “o hífen  nas palavras compostas que designam espécies botânicas e zoológicas”, e exemplifica com, entre outros, “*andorinha-grande, cobra-capelo, formiga-branca; andorinha-do-mar, cobra-d’água*”. *Foca-leopardo* designa uma espécie zoológica, logo leva hífen.

Encontrei *foca-leopardo* apenas num único dicionário, a Infopédia, da Porto Editora, que aceita os dois plurais: [*focas-leopardo*](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/focas-leopardo) ou [*focas-leopardos*](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/focas-leopardos). O [Vocabulário Ortográfico da Academia Brasileira de Letras](https://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario) não traz *foca-leopardo*, mas aceita igualmente os dois plurais para nomes do mesmo tipo: *focas-harpa* ou *focas-harpas*; *focas-monge* ou *focas-monges*.

Este tipo de nome composto é um caso bicudo. Nomes compostos de dois substantivos normalmente marcam o plural nos dois elementos: *tio**s**-avô**s**, tenente**s**-coronéi**s**, surdo**s**-mudo**s***, etc. *Foca-leopardo* admite também a marcação do plural apenas no primeiro elemento, *foca**s**-leopardo*, basicamente porque *foca-leopardo* é uma foca e não um leopardo, e *leopardo* serve apenas para especificar o tipo de foca. Nestes casos, a *Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra recomenda que se marque o plural só no primeiro elemento. Acontece que esta  recomendação parece não ser seguida lá muito religiosamente, e em muitos nomes compostos deste tipo os dicionários registam os dois plurais (com s só no primeiro elemento ou em ambos). Vê [esta pergunta sobre o plural de nomes compostos em geral](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3550/plural-de-substantivos-compostos-e-g-por-que-cavalos-vapor-mas-decretos-lei) e também [esta sobre o plural de *vale-compra*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4065/qual-%C3%A9-o-plural-de-vale-compra?noredirect=1&lq=1), em que há também o duplo plural.