# Plural de dia a dia

Tags: preposições, número-gramatical, substantivos

O substantivo masculino dia a dia significa cotidiano, o conjunto de atividades desenvolvidas no correr dos dias; é substantivo composto de elementos ligados por preposição. É correto que, assim como em **pé de moleque**, no plural, **pés de moleque**, só o primeiro elemento varia, sendo **dias a dia**? Por exemplo, *em seus dias a dia, há muitos afazeres*. Pessoalmente, parece soar melhor **dia a dias**. Além disso, também há regra que diz que quando os elementos do composto são repetidos (e.g. **corre-corres**), só o segundo elemento varia. Qual é a regra aplicável aqui?

**ATUALIZAÇÃO:** O [verbete](https://aulete.com.br/dia%20a%20dia) mostra que o plural é dia a dias. Ainda assim, gostaria de saber o porquê.

Comment: O atual Acordo eliminou o emprego de hífen na diferenciação entre a locução adverbial (dia a dia) e a locução substantiva (dia-a-dia).

Comment: Tudo bem. A ideia continua a mesma.

Comment: Perguntas relacionadas: [Plural de substantivos compostos: e.g. por que “cavalos-vapor” mas “decretos-leis”?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/3550/2764), [Plural: Focas-leopardo, Focas-leopardos ou focas leopardos?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/9126/2764).

Answer (score 2):

Supondo que não ser mais ligado por hifens seja inconsequente, é possível que se trate da [regra](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf28.php):

> c) Flexiona-se somente o **segundo** elemento, quando formados de:
> [...] palavras repetidas ou imitativas = reco-reco e reco-reco**s**

Também mencionada [aqui](https://www.normaculta.com.br/plural-dos-substantivos-compostos/):

> Flexão apenas do segundo elemento [...] Nos substantivos compostos em que há repetição do primeiro elemento:
>
> zum-zum - zum-zuns;
> tico-tico - tico-ticos;
> lufa-lufa - lufa-lufas;