# Qual é o plural de "função potência"?

Tags: número-gramatical

Em matemática, estudamos vários tipos de funções:

- Uma **função constante** é uma função do tipo f(x)=c.
- Uma **função potência** é uma função da forma f(x)=x^n.
- Uma **função polinomial** é uma função do tipo f(x)=polinômio.
- Uma **função racional** é uma função do tipo f(x)=polinômio/polinômio.

Se é correto falar em "funções constantes", "funções polinomiais" e "funções racionais", porque é errado dizer "funções potências"? Ou não é errado?

Pergunto isso por dois motivos. Primeiro, me soa estranho. Segundo, parece que a maioria das aparições no Google registra "funções potência" em vez de "funções potências" (porém há muitos casos das duas formas).

Comment: Podes querer ver também [esta pergunta sobre plural de nomes compostos](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3550/plural-de-substantivos-compostos-e-g-por-que-cavalos-vapor-mas-decretos-lei).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sugiro usar "**funções (de) potência**".

Nos demais exemplos ("constante", "polinomial", "racional") temos apenas adjetivos, enquanto "potência" é um substantivo — por isso inclusive também se usa o termo "função **de** potência", e essa preposição está implícita na expressão sem ela: "função [de / do tipo] potência". E, como [explicado](https://www.dicio.com.br/plural-das-palavras-compostas/) para substantivos compostos:

> Apenas o primeiro elemento vai para o plural [...] [quando] o segundo elemento limita o sentido do primeiro

e aqui "potência" limita o tipo de função a que se refere. Outro exemplo do tipo é "[soluções tampão](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solu%C3%A7%C3%A3o_tamp%C3%A3o)".

Outra linha de argumentação para o plural apenas da primeira palavra do termo é a preposição "de" implícita, que, ao menos para substantivos compostos ligados por hífen leva à [recomendação](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf28.php):

> Flexiona-se somente o primeiro elemento, quando formados de:
>
> substantivo + preposição oculta + substantivo = cavalo-vapor e cavalos-vapor

Dito isso, "pedra-sabão", em que "sabão" claramente limita o sentido de "pedra", formalmente [admite](https://dicionario.priberam.org/pedra-sab%C3%A3o) ambos os plurais, "pedras-sabão" e "pedras-sabões" (embora esse último pessoalmente me soe muito mal), ilustrando talvez o comentário de José Neves Henriques no [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/plural-dos-nomes-compostos/3494):

> O plural dos nomes compostos é, por vezes, complicado e um tanto controverso.

E de fato não me parece que se possa provar que pluralizar "potência" está errado, mas, pelas razões acima (e pelos meus ouvidos), sugiro não a flexionar.

Comment: Eu também nunca diria "pedras-sabões". De acordo com o primeiro critério que apresentas seria só "pedras-sabão" ("sabão" especifica o tipo de pedra). Esse é também o critério do Cunha e Cintra (vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3550/plural-de-substantivos-compostos-e-g-por-que-cavalos-vapor-mas-decretos-lei)), mas já tinha visto plurais violando esse critério em dicionários.

Comment: @Jacinto Hehe... você cita na tua resposta exatamente a mesma frase do JNH que eu na minha. :)